# My file path can play with Media but got Error Codes 1 with fileSystem.root.getFile

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm try to use `FileChooser` to pick up a audio file and read it as Data URL to stored in a JavaScript object, I got the `FileUrl` through `FileChooser.open()` call back, and use `FilePath.resolveNativePath()` to get the file path; I can use `Media` to play audio of the file path perfectly, but when I use `fileSystem.root.getFile(theFilePath)` to get it as a `FileEntry` I got error code `1`; I can't recognize whether the path format invalid for `fileSystem.root.getFile()` or I've missing some permission setting.

Here is my code:

```
var selAudioFilePath;

$("#btnSelAudio").click(function(e) {
    fileChooser.open(function (fileUrl) {

        fileUrl = decodeURIComponent(fileUrl);

        window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(
            fileUrl,
            ResolveNativePathSuccess,
            function(err) {
                alert("resolveNativePath Error: " + err)
            }
        );
    });
});

function ResolveNativePathSuccess(filePath) {
    selAudioFilePath = filePath;

    var mediaPlay = new Media(
            selAudioFilePath,
            function(){ alert("Play OK!"); }, // got this call back
            function(err){ alert("Play error! " + err.code); }
    );

    mediaPlay.play(); // played perfectly

    window.requestFileSystem(
            LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            RequestFileSystemSuccess, //FileSystem requested successfully, full path is "/"
            function(err){
                alert("requestFileSystem Error: " + err.code);
            }
    );

}

function RequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(
        selAudioFilePath, 
        {create: false},
        function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(
                    function(file){
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            console.log("Read as data URL:" + evt.target.result);
                        };

                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        alert("fileEntry.file() fail: error code = " + err.code); // ** got this call back, err code = 1 ** :(
                    }
            );
        },
        function(err) {
            alert("fileSystem.root.getFile() fail: error code = " + err.code);
        }               
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem.

After a little survey I got the error code `1` is `FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR`, it tells me the `fileSystem.root` can't recognizing my file URL correctly, then I made the following changes:

1. add `"file://"` protocol on start of `window.FilePath.resolveNativePath` call back result path string.
2. use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI()` instead of `fileSystem.root.getFile()`, to got the FileEntry

and it works.